# Is EXIF data scrubbed from images uploaded to all Stackexchange sites?

Tags: support, privacy

Suppose I upload a picture taken from a digital camera onto SE... is my privacy protected and is all EXIF data scrubbed from StackExchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy to test, I just uploaded a small picture taken with my phone, and ran `exiv2` on it:

```
File name       : sample.jpg
File size       : 23428 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 204 x 153
Camera make     : SAMSUNG
Camera model    : GT-I9300
...
```

Then I uploaded it here:

[image: uploaded sample]

The md5sum differs, and the file does not seem contain any Exif data:

```
File name       : XRiYI.jpg
File size       : 6509 Bytes
MIME type       : image/jpeg
Image size      : 153 x 204
XRiYI.jpg: No Exif data found in the file
```

See also the [help pages of Imgur, the service used by SE](https://imgur.com/help/uploading#maxsize):

> The maximum file size limits vary based on type of user. For all users
>   the maximum non-animated file size you can upload is 20MB. **The image
>   is then compressed down to a smaller size** based on the user type.

Conclusion: **Exif data is stripped after upload**, this saves space for the image host. There is no need to worry about the *metadata*, but beware when uploading pictures of yourself being drunk or neighborhood.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it appears so. At least basic tools find no EXIF data, I haven't dug in with specialized forensic tools. The image is also recompressed.

```
$ exif IMG_20131019_163230.jpg  # the original image (taken by my phone camera)
EXIF tags in 'IMG_20131019_163230.jpg' ('Intel' byte order):
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
Tag                 |Value
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
Image Width         |2560
Image Length        |1920
…
Name of GPS processi|11 bytes undefined data
GPS date            |2013:10:19
--------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
EXIF data contains a thumbnail (8149 bytes).
$ exif 8Na8r.jpg # uploaded via the “Add image” button
Corrupt data
The data provided does not follow the specification.
ExifLoader: The data supplied does not seem to contain EXIF data.
$ exiftime 8Na8r.jpg
8Na8r.jpg: couldn't find Exif data
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Wonder if it's being watermarked. Also doesn't mean Imgur does not record the EXIF data somewhere.